# Copy tree structure recursive - Adjacency List Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to copy a tree structure from one database table to another. The structure is an Adjacency List Model. It looks like:

```
id|parent_id|position
1|0|1
2|1|1
3|1|2
4|0|2
5|4|1
```

It is **necessary** that the id's are regenerated (autoinc) in the other table! I have the following functions:

```
/**
 * Copy a single node and return the new id
 */
public function copyNode($sn_data){
    $this->db2->insert('items_configurations', $sn_data);
    return $this->db2->insert_id();
}

/**
 * Return a list of child nodes as an assoziative array
 * from a given parent
 */
public function childList($parent_id){
    $tmp  = 'SELECT parent_id,item_id,template_id,position FROM items_templates WHERE parent_id='.$parent_id;
    $tmp .= ' ORDER BY position';
    $query=$this->db2->query($tmp);
    return $query->result_array();
}

/**
 * Copy the whole tree structure through an recursive function
 */
public function copyTree($node_data,$given_parent){
    $new_parent = $this->copyNode($node_data);
    $new_data   = $this->childList($node_data['id']);
    if(is_array($new_data)){
        foreach($new_data as $new_node_data) :
            $new_node_data['parent_id'] = $given_parent;
            $new_node_data['configuration_id'] = $node_data['configuration_id'];
            $this->copyTree($new_node_data,$new_parent);
        endforeach;
    }
}


/**
 * First call of the function for example:
 */    
$this->copyTree(array('parent_id' => 0,'item_id' => 40,'template_id' => 6,'position' => 1),0);
```

I want to do it recursive, but it only copies the first two lines. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You must use current node `id` as the parent_id when you are traversing recursively. And you are using it's parent_id in `childList`:

```
parent_id='.$parent_id;
```

Must be 
    parent_id='.$id;

You are getting peers of this node rather, then it's children.

2.Also I am suspicious about the marked line:

```
if(is_array($new_data)){
    foreach($new_data as $new_node_data) :
        $new_node_data['parent_id'] = $new_parent;//<--
        $this->copyTree($new_node_data);
    endforeach;
}
```

Because you have a new parent_id and then is using it with the old table in childList function. Check, whether the parameter is correct.

Comment: Hi, first thanks. If I do this like you told the id's are copied! This is not correct and my major problem. I have to copy the tree structure from table 1 to table 2, but the id's in table 2 are generated by autoinc! For example if I want to copy a tree twice or change it in table 2.

Comment: @grolle Pass the new parent_id as a separate parameter and use it inside `copyNode` function

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've edited my first post, but it don't work?! Another thing is what to do with the first level items (parent_id=0)?

Comment: You start with the 1-st level items and then copy each of them and it's children. Unfortunately, it's hard for me to say, why your code doesn't work without being able to debug it. Try printing the critical variables and checking their values.